# Realm init fails /data/user

Tags: android, crash, realm

```
Realm.init(this);
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
        .name("default.realm")
        .modules(Realm.getDefaultModule(), new RealmCoreModule())
        .schemaVersion(10)
        .migration(new SampleRealmMigration())
        .build());
```

> Fatal Exception: ***java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.zappos.android.ZapposApplication: io.realm.internal.IOException: failed to create temporary directory: /data/user/0/com.zappos.android/files/.realm.temp***
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4800)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:157)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1417)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
>   ***Caused by io.realm.internal.IOException: failed to create temporary directory: /data/user/0/com.sample.android/files/.realm.temp
>          at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.initialize(SharedRealm.java:48)
>          at io.realm.Realm.init(Realm.java:191)
>          at com.sample.android.SampleApplication.onCreate(SampleApplication.java:223)***
>          at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1014)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4797)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:157)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1417)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)

I've noticed that this fails sometimes and more regularly on LG devices on Android 6.

Disk space was not an issue and neither was RAM. From a little more research it says `/data/user/0` is something that gets returned during multiple user profiles on the phone. I haven't had luck trying to replicate it.

An issue at the project repo has been created github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4430

Comment: Is it possible for you to access the phone? I would like to know if `/data/user/0/com.sample.android/files/.realm.temp` is created or not.

Comment: Unfortunately all these are collected from crashlytics. I'm unable to reproduce it. I don't know what conditions cause this. But I can help you get as much info as possible.

Comment: I created an realm-java issue https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4430 . Could you please comment there about what realm-java version are you using? Let's move discussion there since it is more like a bug somewhere.

Comment: Done, do you want me to close this issue here or leave it open until it is resolved?

Comment: Just leave it here so others can find the github issue from here. Thanks!